# Toggle display of html multiple block using jquery in php site

Tags: jquery, html

I have 3 html block as bellow,

```
<table class="">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="breakdown" href="#">test</a>                                                
            <div style="display: none;padding: 10px;" class="breakdown_details">
                <br/>content here2<br/>
            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="breakdown" href="#">test</a>                                                
            <div style="display: none;padding: 10px;" class="breakdown_details">
                <br/>content here3
            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Initially test links are display but div's contents not display, when I click the test link then corresponding div is open with sliding and perform toggle Acton. I use following script but not properly..

```
$('.breakdown').click(function(){
    $(this).next(".breakdown_details").slideToggle("slow", function(){

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your script is not working as it is correct. Perhaps you are missing the jQuery reference in your html? Or perhaps you have included your script without the `$(document).ready(function () { ... });`? Either way, this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Deif/UxNMT/4/) shows that it is working.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following script,

```
   $('.breakdown').click(function(){
      $(this).next(".breakdown_details").slideToggle("slow", function(){
             $(".breakdown_details").not(this).slideUp("slow");
       });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks **Goldenagebd**  It's work!